# QT signal to thread not being delivered

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

First, I have spend a considerable amount of time researching this topic and have tried an number of different configurations to no avail.  It appears that what is below is close to what is meant to be, but I am still missing something.

I started with this error, also suspicious the program was executing sequentially in spite of my attempts to thread it...

```
QObject::moveToThread: Cannot move objects with a parent
```

Also, `qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();` in any place (or thread attempt) in the program returned the same ID

I then changed my `mainwindow` and `Top_Calc` constructors from this

```
    SDS::SDS(QWidget *parent) : 
        QMainWindow(parent), 
        ui(new Ui::SDS),
        Top_Calc(this)
   {
```

to this

```
   SDS::SDS(QWidget *parent) : 
        QMainWindow(parent), 
        ui(new Ui::SDS)
   {
```

Now, the error is gone, but my signal from the main window doesn't appear to arrive in the appropriate thread although the .isrunning() returns true

MainWindow.cpp

```
    SDS::SDS(QWidget *parent) : 
        QMainWindow(parent), 
        ui(new Ui::SDS)
   {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qRegisterMetaType< Settings >();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SendTopHandles(Settings&)), &Top_Calc, SLOT(ReceiveHandles(Settings&)));

    Top_Calc.moveToThread(&TopThread);
    TopThread.start();
    }

    int SDS::on_StartScan_clicked() {
        emit SendTopHandles(RunSet);
    }
```

MainWindow.h

```
    class SDS : public QMainWindow
    {
         Q_OBJECT

    public:
         explicit SDS(QWidget *parent = 0);
    protected: 
         Settings RunSet;
    private:
        Ui::SDS *ui;
        QThread TopThread;
        TopCalc Top_Calc;
    signals:
        void SendTopHandles(Settings& RunSet);
    }
```

CalcThreads.h

```
     class TopCalc : public QObject
     {
        Q_OBJECT
     public:
        explicit TopCalc(QObject *parent = 0);

     protected:
        Settings* RunSet;
     public slots:
        void ReceiveHandles(Settings& RunSet);
     }
```

CalcThreads.cpp

```
TopCalc::TopCalc(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
}

void TopCalc::ReceiveHandles(Settings& S) {
    RunSet = &S;
}
```

The program never gets to the ReceiveHandles function.  It continues on later commands.  If I remove the QObject parent from the constructor and header file I get the same result.

Should I have put the thread variables inside the main() function instead of the ui constructor as so many examples show?

What am I missing?

Comment: `Private:` and `Signals:` should be lowercase to compile, as mentioned by @mike in a previous discussion.

Comment: this post is really good tutorial on how to run qthreads https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: There is too much code missing from your snippets in order to actually give an answer to this question. Create an MCVE which reproduces the problem and come back.

Comment: When your program has errors, first check that you check for errors... Here, check return value of `connect`, does it succeed?

Comment: Also, is `RunSet` a pointer or not, and in which class? That code looks like it wouldn't even compile...

Comment: the RunSet object is instantiated in the ui thread.  A pointer to it is passed to all threads in order to distribute a common place for settings that come from the UI / hardware during execution.  Before anyone says that I shouldn't do that, it is a producer consumer relationship where all variables have only one producer and many consumers and thus thread safe.

Comment: @hyde after looking at the documentation, checking to see if the connect is successful is not as straight forward as it sounds.  How would you propose to do this?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html#operator-bool allows for example assigning return value of `connect` to a `bool` or just using it in `if` condition. So it is as straightforward as it gets in C++, actually.

Comment: @hyde Yes it connects

Comment: Passing a *reference* across threads doesn't work. `RunSet` will be copied behind the scenes. What does it contain, really?

Comment: @peppe it contains a large number of settings and handles for frame grabbers.  The trouble is that the gui thread collects user modifiable settings that the "scanner" thread needs access to in order to establish a connection with the frame grabbers.  However, the scanner thread is dealing with 4 grabbers running at 2000 frames per second and thus needs to be free from other functions blocking execution.  According to this, there is nothing wrong with passing a pointer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252533/qt-4-3-passing-class-pointer-between-threads

Comment: @bluebass44 you are trying to pass a reference, not a pointer. A reference cannot be copied, which is needed for a `Qt::QueuedConnection`. A pointer can. If you only have one instance of `RunSet` like in your example, why not pass it to the thread in its constructor?